# Python - Creating new vfp Table with dbf module has unreadable memo files

Tags: python, dbf

I'm trying to copy a dbf/ftp Visual FoxPro 9 table and append a couple columns to it and fill them with some data coming from a pandas DataFrame. I'm using the [dbf](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/) module, which seems to work nicely for most of my applications.

This time around, I hit a road bloc: while my code indeed creates the new table and fills it rather nicely, I'm totally unable to access the memo fields afterwards in FoxPro or in my (rather outdated) software still running on it and which needs these new columns.

The memo fields are loaded as 'name M' and transfered to the new table as is. My version of the librairy is 0.98.3 which conda tells me is up to date.

My code:

```
table = dbf.Table(dbf_path).open()

structure = table.structure()
structure[-5] = 'date T NULL'   #<-- I'm doing this because the initial struc for
                                #    this field is 'date T binary' which raise an
                                #    exception and prevents me from doing anything
                                #    afterwards

with table.new(new_dbf_path,
               field_specs=structure,
               ignore_memos=False    #<-- I tried playing with this, but it didn't  
               ) as new:             #    seem to change anything


    new.add_fields(['field_1 N(6,0)', 'field_2 N(6,1)',
                    'field_3 N(6,0)', 'field_4 N(6,1)'])

    count=0
    for record in table:
        listrec = list(record)

        field_1 = data.at[count, 'field_1']
        field_2 = data.at[count, 'field_2']
        field_3 = data.at[count, 'field_3']
        field_4 = data.at[count, 'field_4']

        listrec += [field_1 if not np.isnan(field_1) else -999,
                    field_2 if not np.isnan(field_3) else -999,
                    field_3 if not np.isnan(field_4) else -999,
                    field_4 if not np.isnan(field_5) else -999
                    ]

        new.append(tuple(listrec))
        count+=1

table.close()
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors -- can you send me a sample of the before and after dbf files?

Comment: Just sent you an email with the files. I hope we can figure this out!

Comment: I am still investigating this as I need to do it again. It would appear that my memo files are empty once created (from VFP's point of view, I can reload them just fine in dbf or dbfread), which would explain why I can't open them.

My original table is showing a width of 10 for the memo files, but the one created by dbf has a witdh of 4. I tried changing it but it has ramifications everywhere in the librairy and I couldn't get it to work yet. Could it be related?

Answer (score 0):

I was having troubles with memo fields working correctly when creating VFP tables using the dbf library too where I couldn't open the memo fields from VFP, perhaps due to a bug in the dbf library. It seems that when you create a table using this library where you set *dbf_type="vfp"* the .dbf created doesn't work fully, since setting *dbf_type="fp"* and using memo fields works just fine.

A workaround that I found was to create 'framework' .dbf and .fpt files that did function correctly using Microsoft VFP. In my case, this was an empty table with all of the fields I wanted. I then copied these .dbf and .fpt files that I wanted to work on in Python **using the file system:**

```
shutil.copy(pathToFrameworkDbf, pathToFinalDbf)
shutil.copy(pathToFrameworkFpt, pathToFinalFpt)
```

Then, open that copy as a table using the dbf library.

```
table = dbf.Table(filename=pathToFinalDbf)
table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
```

Now when I use the dbf library to add rows with memo fields in them to this table, they seem to work correctly.